# DataGridView Row Selector (Record Selector) Doesn't Select Actually

Tags: c#, datagridview, mouseevent

```
var hit = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
int rowHit = hit.RowIndex;
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
dataGridView1.Rows[rowHit].Selected = true;
```

This is my code but and it select the row when I click the right mouse button, but record selector arrow doesn't change to the current selected row. Record selector arrow only change if I click on left mouse button. I want when I click right or left click, selector change. How can I slove this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear where the posted code is executed. I am guessing in the grids `MouseDown` event?

When you “left” click on a cell in the grid, then it becomes “selected” and the “Record selector” as you describe moves to that row in the grid. So calling the grids `HitTest` method to find the cells row and column index, and setting the row to `Selected` to move the “Record selector” to that row... is redundant as the grid will do this any way.

When you “right” click on a cell then obviously none of this happens.

It is not clear what you are wanting to accomplish here, however, one thing that may help, is to understand that the grids `CurrentCell` may not necessarily always be the grids “selected” cell. And whatever row the grids `CurrentCell` is… is the row where the “Record selector” will be displayed.

So, in the posted code you could add the following lines to the posted code and it should change the “Record selector” the row under the “right” mouse click.

```
int colHit = hit.ColumnIndex;
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[rowHit].Cells[colHit];
```

This should work, but as previously noted, this is redundant when the user “left” clicks on the grid. In addition, using the grids `HitTest` appears unnecessary if you subscribed to the grids `CellMouseClick` event. In this event we will know which cell was clicked and we could simply check to see “which” mouse button was clicked. In this case, we would look for the “right” mouse button clicks and then simply change the grids `CurrentCell` to that cell using the code above. Something like…

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense.